# Select data com Between no formato Varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web

Estou refazendo a pergunta pois não consegui o resultado desejado, gostaria de fazer um select no campo data porém o between não está funcionando, acredito que seja devido ao meu campo data estar no formato VARCHAR, testei o código abaixo:

```
("SELECT * FROM caixa WHERE data BETWEEN '01/05/2017' AND '31/05/2017'");
```

porém  ele selecionou todos os registros e não apenas os que possuiam data entre 01/05/2017 e 31/05/2017.

Comment: O formato que está gravando no varchar é dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: sim. está no mesmo formato do código acima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O correto é armazenar datas em campos do tipo `date`, `datetime` ou `timestamp`, mas caso você não possa reestruturar sua tabela, com a função `STR_TO_DATE` você consegue converter `string` para `date`. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM caixa WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31/05/2017', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Para saber mais sobre `STR_TO_DATE` [clique aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Answer (score 3):

#### Gambiarra

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    caixa
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT (
        DATA,
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-31 23:59:59'
```

#### O Certo

Mudar o tipo de campo para um campo tipo data. Tem vários conforme mencionado na outra resposta.

Comment: No caso se eu mudar eu perderei todos registros certo? Essa gambiarra tem algum contra?(além da bagunça)

Comment: Deixar o tipo de campo como varchar complica quando você precisa fazer verificações como agora. Tem que ficar quebrando a cabeça para converter os dados. Quando se trabalha com o dado correto isso é evitado. Cria uma coluna do lado do tipo `timestamp`.

Comment: Daí você faz um update para atualizar essa coluna com a data correta, fazendo a conversão da outra coluna.

Comment: ok obrigado pela dica, mas no caso seria no formato date e ele salvaria no formato yyyy-mm-dd certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Salvaria dessa forma, com hora, minuto e segundo...

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM caixa WHERE cast(data as date) BETWEEN '01/05/2017' AND '31/05/2017'
```

Comment: Esse `CAST` não funciona porque o conteúdo do campo data esta no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`, neste caso o `CAST` retorna `NULL`.

Comment: Funciona no SQL Server, não funciona mesmo pro Mysql